# javascript class problem

Tags: javascript

Examine this code

```
    var _class=function()
    {
        this.Test=100;
        this.Callback=function(msg)
        {
            alert(msg+"\r\n"+this.Test);
        }
    }

    function run(call)
    {
        call("Hello world");
    }

    var obj=new _class();
    run(obj.Callback);
```

I got the result :

```
    [Alert]
    Hello world
    undefined
```

but when i call 
      obj.Callback("Hello world")

i got expected

```
    [Alert]
    Hello world
    100
```

why ?

thank for help

Comment: why not?  That is just how js works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no intrinsic relationship between an object and the functions defined "inside" it.  The **only** thing that determines the value of `this` (called the "receiving" object) in a function call is the way in which the function is called.

- Call a function with `object.func()`, and `this` will be bound to `object`.
- Call a function with "call()" or "apply()", and `this` is determined by the first parameter.
- If a function is called without any implicit object context, however, as in your "callback" example, then `this` won't refer to <strike>anything</strike> your object — it will refer to `window` (or whatever the global context is).

The trick is that when you want to use a function as if it were a "method" on an object, such that the relationship remains intact even though the function reference has been yanked away from the object, you can pre-bind `this` in a couple of ways:

1. You can wrap the function in *another* function, so that you explicitly retain `this` in a closure.
2. You can use ".bind()" to (essentially) do the same thing.

The first way would look like this:

```
run(function() { obj.Callback(); });
```

The second way would look like this:

```
run(obj.Callback.bind(obj));
```

JavaScript is quite different from languages like C# or Java in this respect. In those languages, a function is sort-of stuck forever in a relationship with its class (or instances of its class).  Not JavaScript; it really doesn't matter at all, in fact, where a function is defined.  Your "_class" function would be equivalent if it were written like this:

```
function helloThere() { 
   alert(msg + "\r\n" + this.Test);
}

var _class = function() {
    this.Test = 100;
    this.Callback = helloThere;
};
```

*edit* — @jamietre correctly notes that had your "_class" function contained some `var` declarations or local functions, then there most certainly would be a difference (though not with respect to the way `this` behaves when "Callback" is invoked).

*edit again* — Thanks @Koolinc

Comment: Not exactly equivalent. Inner functions have access to the resources of the closure. If there were any private variables in _class then the function `helloThere` in your example would not be able to access them, because it was defined in a different scope. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bd886/

Comment: @jamietre yes that is definitely true, but in this case there were no "interesting" local `var` variables in the function. Had that been the case, then you're right. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: *If a function is called without any implicit object context, however, as in your "callback" example, then this won't refer to anything* -> `this` would refer to the global object I'd say.

Comment: @Koolinc you may be right; I'll do a fiddle. The main point is that you can't rely on it being your own object.

Comment: @Koolinc yes you're right, in the couple cases I did (plain function call, "setTimeout()" callback), it's the global (`window`) object.

Answer (score 1):

this.Test is not defined.  The scope of this in that context is the callback function.

This is a quick fix:

```
var _class=function()
{
    var self = this;
    this.Test=100;
    this.Callback=function(msg)
    {
        console.log(msg+"\r\n"+self.Test);
    }
}
```